# npx create-react-app juxdrive works but deletes and abort after installation

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cmd

`npm config clear cache --force` is not solving the problem and other react projects are unable to start the server.

```
C:\Users\Bismark\Documents\codes>npx create-react-app juxdrive

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\Bismark\Documents\codes\juxdrive.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! errno ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/mini-css-extract-plugin: Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Bismark\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-01T16_04_39_178Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting juxdrive/ from C:\Users\Bismark\Documents\codes
Done.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of solutions you could try

1. If you have package-lock.json inside your node project delete it
2. If you are using Docker image other than 14 try downgrade to 14